# Best practice to fill a table that relates to another with a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to ask what would be the best approach (performance-wise) to split a table into two and relate them with a foreign key.

Lets assume that there is a table that contains tracks called
`rawdata`:

```
           title            |  artist   |     album     
----------------------------+-----------+---------------
 Another One Bites The Dust | Queen     | Greatest Hits
 Asche Zu Asche             | Rammstein | Herzeleid
 Beauty School Dropout      | Various   | Grease
```

and a table `albums` that contain the distinct album titles bound to an id.

```
 id |     title     
----+---------------
  2 | Greatest Hits
 29 | Grease
 30 | Herzeleid
```

I would like to fill table `tracks` where the `album_id` would be a foreign key to `albums`, but I want to figure out which is the optimal way to do so.

```
 id |           title            | album_id 
----+----------------------------+----------
  1 | Another One Bites The Dust |        2
  2 | Asche Zu Asche             |       30
  3 | Beauty School Dropout      |       29
```

I have came up with two ideas:

**a.** Use a join:

```
INSERT INTO tracks(title, album_id)
    SELECT rawdata.title, album.id 
    FROM rawdata
    LEFT JOIN album ON album.title = rawdata.album;
```

**b.** Use a `SELECT - FROM` two tables

```
INSERT INTO tracks(title, album_id)
    SELECT rawdata.title, album.id 
    FROM rawdata, album
    WHERE album.title = rawdata.album;
```

Is any of them better than the other?

Is there any better way to do so?

Comment: You are using a join in both cases. The second one is equivalent with an inner join (not a left join). Regardless of which one you choose, you need to make sure that you join with something that uniquely identifies a row. As an example, I can imagine that there are several rawdata.album greatest hits.

Comment: the information is redundant and so shouldn't be saved twice in the database

Comment: Idea **b)** is just the old-style JOIN syntax which has been replaced **30 years** ago in the SQL-92 standard by the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax (like using `INNER JOIN` ,  `LEFT OUTER JOIN` etc.). Technically, in the end result , both are the same - but option **a.)** is **definitely** the preferred syntax these days

Comment: Thank you. So performance-wise, both a & b are the same. Question: I guess that adding a column `album_id` on `rawdata` and using  a subquery `UPDATE rawdata SET album_id = (SELECT album.id FROM album WHERE album.title = rawdata.album);` is slower due to the subquery. Or this join is equivalent to a subquery too?

Comment: They are not the same `join`, for more information read [FROM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).  The `LEFT JOIN` will include items from the left(rawdata) table that are not included in the album table with the row padded with nulls.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver for the clarification, but in this case there are no tracks that dont point to an album. This is why I said that it is the same when we count performance.